# VSCODE AND PRETTIER: Trailing ">"s causing rest of code to get formatted into a white text color

Tags: visual-studio-code, vue-cli-3, prettier

I'm using VSCODE with ESLINT and Prettier. When writing code, it appears that my editor is converting lines such as:

```
    <template :slot="cancel">Cancel</template>
```

and putting the trailing `>`s on new lines:

```
    <template :slot="cancel"
      >Cancel</template
    >
```

This causes VSCODE to show all the code in a a white font like so:

[image]

My prettier file:

```
module.exports = {
  singleQuote: true,
  semi: false,
  printWidth: 200,
  overrides: [
    {
      files: '*.html',
      options: {
        parser: 'html'
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**What is causing this and how to fix?**